# Wordpress is easy, The client has to learn it, So what do i offer?

Tags: wordpress

*I put this question in "wordpress answers" forum but i hope i can get more information from this active forum*

After spending some time learning it, I am considering using wordpress rather than doing everything from scratch as i am used to.

but I see that the client will manage his content through the WP dashboard, so he has to learn wordpress and i admit that wordpress is really easy to use. **so what do i offer as a service vendor?**

If the user knows how to deal with the posts and the content, it wouldn't take much time or effort for him to learn about plugins and other stuff and he will be on his own soon,

**So what is my job then? Is my job as a website business just to install and configure wordpress? is it hard for the end user to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answers are:

1. Installation
2. Customization of the theme
3. Database management and backups
4. Maintenance of plugins
5. Integrations of other features/functions like payment gateways, lightbox popups, etc.
6. SEO optimization

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you offer:

You slice up your customer's sites into HTML, CSS, weave in Javascript magic and create customized templates for them. You would also presumably be helping them with all the things that go with an online deployment - SEO, etc. This all takes time and specialized skills.

In my opinion, your comment could be likened to this:

"I've shown my customers how to turn the tap on, how to drink water, how to connect a hose to the pipe in the back yard, what do I offer as plumber?"

Comment: some customers ask for wordpress as a requirement, Does that mean that customers see WP from a different point of view?

Comment: I would say that some customers probably prefer Wordpress because configured "normally" it gives them the ability to manage their own content to some extent, without having to engage the developer - and why not; Some charge crazy prices for the most simple changes (eg: @ $500 per word that needs to be changed in the copy, I'd probably want to update that myself too.. :) ) Of course, if anything serious needs to be done, they would probably engage the developer for that.